# Occasional failure of an attack on ElGamal signature

Tags: elgamal-signature

I am following the procedure described on p. 319 of the fourth edition of Douglas Stinson and (since that edition) Maura Paterson's *Cryptography − Theory and Practice* (IBSN 978-1-03-247604-9).

The context is recovery of the nonce $k$ in ElGamal signature in $\mathbb Z_p^*$, assuming nonce reuse. We have two message/signature pairs $\bigl(x_1,(\gamma,\delta_1)\bigr)$ and $\bigl(x_2,(\gamma,\delta_2)\bigr)$. It holds $\gamma=\alpha^k\bmod p$, $\delta_i=(x_i-a\gamma)k^{-1}\bmod(p-1)$ where $\alpha$ is a generator and $a$ is the private key.

We are in the sub-case of $d=\gcd(\delta_1-\delta_2,p-1)\ne1$. It's computed $x'=(x_1-x_2)/d$, $\delta'=(\delta_1-\delta_2)/d$, and $p'=(p-1)/d$.

> Then the congruence $x_1-x_2\equiv k(\delta_1-\delta_2)\pmod{p-1}$ becomes:
> $$x'\equiv k\delta'\pmod{p'}.\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
> Since $\gcd(\delta',p')=1$, we can compute
> $$\epsilon=(\delta')^{-1}\bmod p'.\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
> The value of $k$ is determined modulo $p'$ to be
> $$k=x'\epsilon\bmod p'.\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$
> This yields $d$ candidate values for $k$:
> $$k=x'\epsilon+ip'\bmod(p-1)\tag{4}\label{eq4}$$
> for some $i,0\le i\le d-1$. Of these $d$ candidate values, the (unique) correct one can be determined by testing the condition
> $$\gamma=\alpha^k\pmod p.\tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

I wrote a program that does all calculations with random parameters and notice that not always can I compute $k$ using the formula $\ref{eq4}$. Nevertheless, sometimes it does work. So I wonder if I am doing something wrong, or there is an assumption on the parameters that I am missing.

For example, taking $$p=157, k = 79, a = 139, \alpha= 70, \beta = 152, x_1 = 116, x_2 = 65, \gamma = 87, \delta_1 = 113, \delta_2 =140,$$ we have $d=3$ and the values returned by formula $\ref{eq4}$ are $0, 52, 104$, none of which is equal to $79$.

Comment: Equation $\eqref{eq3}$ is intended to be read $k\equiv x'\epsilon\pmod{p'}$, meaning $x'\epsilon-k$ is a multiple of $p'=(p-1)/d$. Equation $\eqref{eq5}$ can be read as $\gamma\equiv\alpha^k\pmod p$ or $\gamma=\alpha^k\bmod p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question's added example values we get $x'=17$, $\delta'=-9$, $p'=52$, $\epsilon=23$. Then for $i=(0,1,2)$ I get $x'\epsilon+ip'\bmod(p-1)=(79,131,27)$, and equation $\eqref{eq5}$ holds for $i=0$, as claimed by the reference.

I conclude the implementation of equation $\eqref{eq2}$ or $\eqref{eq4}$ is wrong in the program that produced $0,52,104$. An hypothesis is that negative $\delta'$ is mishandled.

I see no mistake in that part of the reference. As noted in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/228047) I wish it used standard and unambiguous notation for modular congruence $u\equiv v\pmod q$ and modular reduction $u=v\bmod q$. Also I think it would be more useful and as easy to find $a$ rather than $k$.

For large $d$, it's worth noting that each step in the sequential search for the full $k$ or $a$ can be organized to cost a single modular multiplication modulo $p$, or further optimized to have cost proportional to $\sqrt d$ such operations, using [baby-step/giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) or [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms).

Comment: Thank you. I will check my implementation.